# 1004 Application-Defined or Object Defined error

Tags: excel, vba

The error appears on the line before end sub, what is the correct way to select the range with the last row calculated?

```
Sub My_Script()
Dim LastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
  ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(LastRow, Columns("D:AH"))).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below select all cells in the `LastRow` only , from Column "D" to Column "AH".

```
Sub My_Script()

Dim LastRow As Long

With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range(.Range("D" & LastRow), .Range("AH" & LastRow)).Select
End With

End Sub
```

If you wanted to select all rows (from row 1 to `LastRow`), from Column "D" to Column "AH".

```
Sub My_Script()

Dim LastRow As Long

With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range(.Range("D1"), .Range("AH" & LastRow)).Select
End With

End Sub
```

**Note**: not sure why you want to `Select` this range ? You can set this `Range` to a variable of type `Range`, and later to `Copy` or whatever you want to do with it. There's hardly a reason to ever use `Select`.